# Insert rows in 3 tables in a single query, SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, php, xampp

I need to insert data into 3 tables in a single query

Table SkillData

| UserIndex | SkillPoint | TotalSkill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5202 | 99 |

Table Emblems

| UserIndex | CountEmblem | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1265 | 1 |

Table Rewards

| UserIndex | Level | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | 1005 |

Comment: So what code do you have so far? What is wrong with three `INSERT` statements?

Comment: save code, since I'm using PHP, and I think doing each query separately is slower the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your reason is to save space in your PHP, you might can use a Stored Procedure for this. Example below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertUserStuff
   @UserIndex INT,
   @SkillPoint INT,
   @TotalSkill INT,
   @CountEmblem INT,
   @Status INT,
   @Level INT,
   @Code INT
AS
BEGIN

   SET XACT_ABORT ON;

   BEGIN TRAN;

   INSERT INTO dbo.SkillData
   (
      UserIndex,
      SkillPoint,
      TotalSkill
   )
   VALUES
   (
      @UserIndex,
      @SkillPoint,
      @TotalSkill
   );

   INSERT INTO dbo.Emblems
   (
      UserIndex,
      CountEmblem,
      Status
   )
   VALUES
   (
      @UserIndex,
      @CountEmblem,
      @Status
   );

   INSERT INTO dbo.Rewards
   (
      UserIndex,
      Level,
      Code
   )
   VALUES
   (
      @UserIndex,
      @Level,
      @Code
   );

   COMMIT TRAN;

END;
```

You can execute this query with:

```
EXEC dbo.InsertUserStuff
   @UserIndex = 1,   
   @SkillPoint = 5202,  
   @TotalSkill = 99,  
   @CountEmblem = 1265, 
   @Status = 1,      
   @Level = 99,       
   @Code = 1005
```

Obviously you need to change the datatypes to whatever you are using.

Comment: this works for me, thanks